# Adding custom header on serving static files with Apache

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Is it possible to send additional custom headers (for example with a wsgi app) before Apache serves static content (image/js/css) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Apache mod_headers module.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html

No way of doing it using mod_wsgi.

You could do it with mod_python if you really had to, but better off trying to do it with builtin Apache modules.